# EWS Managed API : Checking Responses

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using EWS Managed API 2.0. I'm using the Calendaring part where you can book appointments as follows :

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

//Set properties on the appointment.
appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment";
appointment.Body = "The appointment is with Dr. Smith.";
appointment.Start = new DateTime(2009, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0);
appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(2);

//Save the appointment.
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

How can I using the API check the status of the booking and whether it was booked or not due to a conflict in the date (Success/Error/Conflict)? right now I'm able to check this through the outlook, but I'd like to know this information from the API. I've looked into the API documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Appreciate your help/guidance.

Comment: Why is the 50 points alotted but answer not upvoted and accepted? (I deleted mine and upvoted his.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check the availability of all attendees before saving your appointment. `AvailabilityData` will return you `Result` (ServiceResult.Success, ServiceResult.Warning, or ServiceResult.Error) and further you can check `ErrorMessage` property to find proper return message for each conflicting availability. If availability is not conflicting for any of the attendees, you can save your Appointment object.

```csharp
AvailabilityOptions availabilityOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration = 60;
availabilityOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 4;
availabilityOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good;
availabilityOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;

List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
attendees.Add(
    new AttendeeInfo()
    {
        SmtpAddress = "org@acme.com",
        AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer
    });

attendees.Add(
    new AttendeeInfo()
    {
        SmtpAddress = "at1@acme.com",
        AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required
    });

attendees.Add(
    new AttendeeInfo()
    {
        SmtpAddress = "room1@acme.com",
        AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Room
    });

GetUserAvailabilityResults availabilityResults =
        service.GetUserAvailability(
            attendees,
            new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
            AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
            availabilityOptions
        );

// Here check the availability Result and ErrorMessage of each attendees
// availabilityResults.AttendeesAvailability[0].Result
// availabilityResults.AttendeesAvailability[0].ErrorMessage
// ServiceResult.Success
// ServiceResult.Warning
// ServiceResult.Error
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.

but I'm missing something I'd appreciate it if you help me figure it out.

What is the link between AvailabilityData & availabilityOptions ? AvialbilityData is not giving me a response for the meeting time I put in availabilityOptions. It is giving me a list of all the CalendarEvents of the room and then I have to go through them 1 by 1 to see if there is a conflict. Isn't there 1 method/parameter that tells me whether the meeting time I chose in availabilityOptions conflicts with the room I put in attendeesInfo ?